# Clean up after calling nc in eternal bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, debian

I have a minimal script that just listens on a socket and prints whatever shows up at the port basically, and sure, that works fine. However I', having trouble cleaning up after I ^z

- perhaps sigtstp isn't the right way to do this?
- can i make Bash listen to and quit on ctrl+c?
- can i clean the nc process? It keeps occypying the port and forces (well...) kill -9?

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    nc -l -p $1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "Can I make bash listen to ^C?", but try this script (untested, I do not have nc installed):

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=0

cleanup() { (( $pid != 0 )) && kill -9 $pid; }
trap "cleanup" EXIT

while :
do
   nc -l -p $1
   pid=$!
done
```

Comment: Naa, sorry, this doesn't change the behaviour. What i meant was that on CTRL+c i want the script to exit.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot abort "while true ; do sleep 1s ; done" with Ctrl+C?